# Jupyterlab Table dynamic output (sorting, filterung, ...)

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Good evening everyone,

is there a way to dynamically display the output of a table (pandas dataframe) so that you can sort by a column in the output or filter a column?

I would have thought that this should be included in Jupyter by default, but I can't find a setting.

Maybe I just can't find such a setting, so I'm curious about your answers. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension called [**qgrid**](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid).

> Qgrid is a Jupyter notebook widget which uses SlickGrid to render pandas DataFrames within a Jupyter notebook. This allows you to explore your DataFrames with intuitive scrolling, sorting, and filtering controls, as well as edit your DataFrames by double clicking cells.

You can display your `dataframe` with widget, and **sort**, **filter** or even **edit** your data interactively.

```py
import qgrid

qgrid_widget = qgrid.show_grid(dataframe, show_toolbar=True)
qgrid_widget
```

As of now (March, 2021), works with both `jupyter lab: 3.0.10` and `jupyter-notebook : 6.2.0`

**Example screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question in my search and have noticed that QGrid development seems halted (3y ago).

There is even an Issue that discusses options, with a particularly useful comment:
https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid/issues/348#issuecomment-948793377

Among the alternatives I also found DataPane, which looks more recently maintained: https://snyk.io/advisor/python/datapane

Another interesting simpler option is [itables](https://github.com/mwouts/itables)

Comment: Datapane is no longer maintained as of Sept 7 2023. See https://github.com/datapane/datapane#note-datapane-is-no-longer-actively-maintained.